# How to change an HTML elements style, and then revert it onLoad() with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, onload

I have a problem with a Lightbox type modal window not working properly with IE.  I have identified the problem as being due to the style attribute of the hidden image as 'display: none'.  This works fine in all other browsers.  But for IE, I need to change the value onload to 'display: block' and then straight back to 'display: none' which will fix the problem.

Could anyone tell me how I can do this?  I need to apply this rule to multiple divs of class 'image'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css

```
.image{ display:none; }
```

in your html

```
...
<body onload="switch" >
...


<script type="text/javascript">
function switch(){
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("image"); // not supported by all browsers but you can easily find implementations on the web

    for(var index=0;index<divs.length;index++)
    {
        divs[index].style.display='block';
    }
}
</script>

</body>
```

jquery version:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".image").show();
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  I should have mentioned I am using jQuery.  I'll give that a try now

Answer (score 0):

are you using any frameworks at all? I ask because this can change the location that you put the following code.

I'm not positive if this works in IE but it may:

```
<img ... onload="this.style.display='block';this.style.display='none';">
```

Failing that put it in your body/document onLoad function (if you don't have one create one).

```
function docOnLoad()
{
   ...
   document.getElementById('img_in_question').style.display = 'block';
   document.getElementById('img_in_question').style.display = 'none';
   ...
}
```

Edit: fixing my horribad spelling.